# Label Change in a loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops

```
 public partial class Balloon : Form
    {
        public Balloon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TopMost = true;
            Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width - 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height - 8);


            InstallStart2();
        }

        private async void InstallStart2()
        {

            if (Dot35 == "Yes")
            {
                this.Titel.Text = "The Knowhow Installer is installing:";
                this.Action.Text = "Microsoft .Net Framework 2 & 3";
                if (File.Exists(root + Installfolder + "dotnetfx35.exe"))
                {
                    Process process = Process.Start(root + Installfolder + "dotnetfx35.exe", "/q /norestart");

                    while (!process.HasExited) ;

                    bool installFinished1 = false;
                    int k = -1;
                    string[] dots = new string[] { "Microsoft .Net Framework 2 & 3.", "Microsoft .Net Framework 2 & 3..", "Microsoft .Net Framework 2 & 3..." };

                    while (!installFinished1)
                    {
                        Action.Text = dots[++k % 3];
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
                    }

                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.TopMost = false;
                    int num = (int)MessageBox.Show("dotnetfx35.exe not found", "Error");
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));







            if (Dot45 == "Yes")
            {
                this.Titel.Text = "The Knowhow Installer is installing:";
                this.Action.Text = "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5";
                if (File.Exists(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFx45.exe"))
                {
                    Process process = Process.Start(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFX45.exe", "/q");

                    bool installFinished = false;
                    int k = -1;
                    string[] dots = new string[] { "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.", "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5..", "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5..." };

                    while (!installFinished)
                    {
                        Action.Text = dots[++k % 3];
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
                    }





                    while (!process.HasExited) ;

                }
                else
                {
                    this.TopMost = false;
                    int num = (int)MessageBox.Show("dotnetFx45.exe not found", "Error");
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));


            this.Action.Text = "Done";

            new SoundPlayer(root + otherfolder + "Done.wav").Play();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = dir;
            this.Close();
            new InstallDone().Show();




        }

    }
```

This is a part of the code and it works for the first installation, but i can not find out where to put `bool installFinished1 = true;` to make it go to the next. Now it just stays at Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5... (it change from 1 to 3 dots in a loop)

Comment: What happens when you use the code you posted here?

Comment: Please specify your application type (console, winforms, mvc, etc)

Comment: Installing dotnet from a dotnet app? If you use a clickonce installer, you can add that as a prerequisite.

Comment: What happens when you use your first codeblock inside the while of your second block (instead of that empty statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it have to be `await` then this is simplest way:

```
bool installFinished = false;
int k = -1;
string[] dots = new string[] { "Installing.", "Installing..", "Installing..." };

while (!installFinished)
{
    Action.Text = dots[++k % 3];
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
}
Action.Text = "Finished";
```

When you finish install, set:

```
installFinished = true;
```

Above loop will stop, and `Action.Text` being set to `Finished`.

Other way, you can use timer.

**Edit:**

Base on your updated code:

```
using System.Threading;

bool installFinished = false;

void Install_net45()
{
    Process process = Process.Start(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFX45.exe", "/q");

    while (!process.WaitForExit(1000))
    {
    }
    installFinished = true;
    // Clean up
}

private async void InstallStart2()
{
    if (Dot45 == "Yes")
    {
        this.Titel.Text = "The Knowhow Installer is installing:";
        this.Action.Text = "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5";
        if (File.Exists(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFx45.exe"))
        {

            installFinished = false;

            Thread t = new Thread(Install_net45);
            t.Start();

            int k = -1;
            string[] dots = new string[] { "Installing.", "Installing..", "Installing..." };

            while (!installFinished)
            {
                Action.Text = dots[++k % 3];
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
            }
            Action.Text = "Finished";
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
        else
        {
            this.TopMost = false;
            int num = (int)MessageBox.Show("dotnetFx45.exe not found", "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tobbe you have to declare `installFinished` outside your method. When you finish install, call `installFinished = true;`. If you declare it inside your method it will not work.

Comment: Iam loosing my mind... soon i will make a gif picture and use that =)

Comment: It not my code wrong, but you use not correct. If you can post how you use this code, I will help you solve this problem.

Comment: It still will not exit

Comment: @Tobbe Check my edit and tell me if this function run or not: `MessageBox.Show("Test");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Action.Text = "Installing.";
Process process = Process.Start(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFX45.exe", "/q");
while(!process.WaitForExit(1000)){
   Action.Text += ".";
}
```

But, if you're doing this in an event handler in a windows forms application, this won't work as you expect. You'll be blocking the UI thread and so it never gets a chance to re-paint and show the updated text. In that case, you should use a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), with this in the `DoWork`:

```
Process process = Process.Start(root + Installfolder + "dotnetFX45.exe", "/q");
while(!process.WaitForExit(1000)){
   worker.ReportProgress(0.5);
}
```

And then update the `Text` property by adding `.`s in the `ProgressChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RxNet, sample code

```
var interval = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
interval.Subscribe(
    () => Action.Text += ".", 
    () => Action.Text = "Completed");
```